# .htaccess subdomain argument not accessible in query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, dynamic, url-rewriting, subdomain

I have written the following rules in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain\.com 
RewriteCond %1 !^www$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/news/news-details\.php$
RewriteRule (.*) news.php?div=%1
```

What it does is transfer the request the news.php file with the **div** variable equal to `news/news-details.php`. I do not need the div to be like that. I need the value of the subdomain that has been written with the domain like if the user is coming from `user.domain.com/news/news-details.php`. I need the div variable in the news.php file to be user i.e. `news.php?div=user`.

EDIT:
Here is now the Htaccess code It is causing problem for the root news details page Options

```
+FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# For Accessing News Details Page for root http://www.domain.com/news/news-details.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/news-details.php$ news.php [QSA,NC,L]


# For Accessing News Details Page http://user.domain.com/news/news-details.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST) !^www\.
RewriteRule ^news/news-details.php$  news.php?div=%1 [QSA,NC,L


# For www.domain.com it should go to the index page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]


# For Accessing Divisions Page user.domain.com should go to domain.com/divisions.php?division=user
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ /divisions.php?division=%1 [L]
```

AGAIN EDIT:

Here these two rules are conflicting

```
# For www.domain.com it should go to my-index.php page
#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ my-index.php [NC,L]


# For Page URL http://www.domain.com/news/news-details.php
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/news/news\-details\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ my-news.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/news/news\-details.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+)\.domain\.com$  [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !^www$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ news.php?div=%1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/news/news\-details\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ news.php [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+)\.domain\.com$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ divisions.php?division=%1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Yes that is working for the dynamic domain but when i type www.domain.com/news/news-details.php it is taking me to the index file. I want this to direct to the same news file without the user argument? how you do that

Comment: you mean when I type: www.domain.com I see news.php (with no param) and when I use: user.domain.com I use: php?user=user?

Comment: Nope when i type www.domain.com/news/news-details.php it should go to news.php but without the argument and for the subdomain the code you wrote is just working fine. But now when i type www.domain.com/news/news-details.php it is taking me to the index.php file Not the news.php??

Comment: view my updated answer. www.domain.com/news/news-details.php => news.php without any params.

Comment: Do you think this line is correct RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain\.com [NC] this is not taking me to the desired file news.php

Comment: You can look at the full htaccess file that i have edited in the posted question. what is causing the browser from not going to the news.php file for the www.domain.com/news/news-details.php call

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L] creates a conflict with news/news-details.php. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: It is still conflicting with the index file.